# Using a 2-D array of Buttons ins Xamarin

Tags: ios, arrays, button, xamarin

I am attempting to make a simple game in Xamarin where the player is given a field of buttons and is able to draw lines between them in order to complete a square. Eventually I want to give the player the option to make the field an arbitrary size of their choosing, so I start by filling a two dimensional array of `UIButton` objects, the size of which will eventually be user defined (in my tests, it's 3x3):

```
public void CreateBtnArray(int x, int y)
{
    int posX = 15;
    int posY = 45;
    UIButton[,] ButtonArray = new UIButton[x,y];

    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                var frame = new RectangleF (posX, posY, 50, 50);
                ButtonArray [i, j] = new UIButton(frame);
                ButtonArray [i, j].SetImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("GameButtons/uibuttonnormal.jpg"), UIControlState.Normal);
                ButtonArray [i, j].SetImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("GameButtons/uibuttonhighlighted.jpg"), UIControlState.Highlighted);
                View.Add(ButtonArray[i,j]);
            }
            posX = 15;
            posY += 100;
        }
    }
```

This works fine, but then I want the user to only be able to draw a line to adjacent buttons, so I attempted to add a `TouchUpInside` event to each button in the array as the array was being built, so that the loop in my method became:

```
for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                var frame = new RectangleF (posX, posY, 50, 50);
                ButtonArray [i, j] = new UIButton(frame);
                ButtonArray [i, j].SetImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("GameButtons/uibuttonnormal.jpg"), UIControlState.Normal);
                ButtonArray [i, j].SetImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("GameButtons/uibuttonhighlighted.jpg"), UIControlState.Highlighted);
                posX += 100;

                ButtonArray[i,j].TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => 
                {
                    if(FirstButtonClicked == null)
                        FirstButtonClicked = ButtonArray[i  , j];
                    //This else if should be where the button checks if it's adjacent to the first button clicked
                    else if(FirstButtonClicked == ButtonArray[1, 1] || 
                            FirstButtonClicked == ButtonArray[i + 1, j] ||
                            FirstButtonClicked == ButtonArray[i, j + 1] ||
                            FirstButtonClicked == ButtonArray[i, j - 1])
                    {
                        //Do Stuff
                    }
                };
                View.Add(ButtonArray[i,j]);
            }
            posX = 15;
            posY += 100;
        }
    }
```

The code complies without error then, but when I attempt to click on a button I get an `Array Index Out of Range` Exception. I think the `TouchUpInside` event is using the last known values of `i` and `j`, rather than the Array Index of the button being clicked. Everything I've found so far seems to assume that the buttons were created with a specific, easy to reference name, rather than arbitrarily like I have here. How do I properly attach the `TouchUpInside` events to each button so that I can also check if a second button pressed is adjacent in the array to the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by giving each assigning each button an `Accessibility Identifier` when they were created using `i.ToString() + j.ToString()` as the identifier for the button, and then attaching each button to a generic event handler. When I needed to interact with each button later on then I was able to do so using `sender.AccessibilityIdentifier` in my generic handler.